# Regex How do I parse the Key Value pair in a string?

Tags: regex, lucene

I'm trying to do an advanced search and I want to narrow down the search string with fields to search on.

Example: 
filename:"\temp location\files\here" fileType:html

This should give me the following group:

- **filename** : \temp location\files\here
- **fileType** : html

How do I parse the key value pair including the values inside a quotation with space?

**Regex I have so far:**
(\w+)\s?:\s?([^\s]+)

**Here is an example of what I have so far:**

https://regex101.com/r/dJ65e2/3

**Update**: I was able to figure it out and the answer is at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225825/978765

Comment: Posted a possible answer, but it's fairly narrow in scope. If it doesn't meet your needs, let me know and I'll see what I can do to adjust it.

Comment: Nick Reed no it doesn't work if I have to do it two different searches. I'm sure it can be done on a single search. I found the following somewhat related to what i'm looking for: https://regex101.com/r/rR1fI0/1

Comment: edited the answer - that should search both at once. You can combine regexes with `|` if need be - as many as you want! (Though it will start to get confusing if you combine too many into one long line.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think This should do the trick: https://regex101.com/r/U1zvEd/2

```
/(\w+)\s?:\s?[\"|']?([^\"|'|\s]+)/g
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the first match group will be quotes and the second match group won't be in quotes, you can use two regexes to find either pair separately. Note that both of these expect the key to be a single word.

`(\w+)\s?:\s?"([ \S]*?)"` will give you a group with whatever word is before the parenthesis, and a group returning whatever's in the quotes.

`(\w+)\s?:\s?([^"\s]\S*[^"])` will give you a group with whatever word is before the parenthesis, and a group returning whatever's *not* in the quotes.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/dJ65e2/4) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/dJ65e2/5).

Edit: you can use the `|` operator to search both at once.

`(\w+)\s?:\s?"([ \S]*?)"|(\w+)\s?:\s?([^"\s]\S*[^"])`

[Try it here.](https://regex101.com/r/dJ65e2/6)